# How do I create and make the following Bootstrap Navbar work?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

The Navbar I'm creating has two input fields, a submit button, a dropdown, and two additional buttons. When I run the code it looks exactly the way I want it to look like. See the first image below.
However several issues occur while using it.
The first occurs because there is a Bootstrap dropdown above it in the same page. The 'Select an Existing Net' you see in the image below. When any item in that dropdown is selected it replace the 'Show/Hide' dropdown button in the navbar (in purple) you see in the second image. If you select something from the 'Show/Hide', it replaces the 'Select an Existing Net' title, making both useless.

I have asked this question before but did not explain it very well or show the images. I've also included the navbar code below the 'Existing Net' dropdown is created in PHP code calling from a MySQL data base. The code for that is also included.

```
<?php              
echo ('<button id="dpbutton" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"> Select an Existing Net  -- (Green means its an open net)
    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>

<ul id="allnets" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="ALLNETS">
<li role="presentation">
    <a href = "#" onclick = "showActivities(\"0\")">Show All Stations in DB</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>');

        foreach($db_found->query("SELECT netid, activity, logdate, frequency, netcall, timeout,
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT netid) 
            FROM NetLog 
            WHERE netid <> '0' and logdate >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 90 DAY)
              $andLine
            GROUP BY netid 
            ORDER BY netid  DESC
            ") as $act){

            if ("$act[timeout]" == "") {    
                $netCall = "$act[netcall], Net #: $act[netid] --> $act[activity] of $act[logdate]"; 
                echo ("<li role='presentation' class=' bg-success ' data-value=\"$act[netid]\">
                    <a href='#' role='menuitem' onclick = 'showActivities($act[netid])'>
                        $netCall
                    </a></li>
                    <li class=\"divider\"></li>");
            } else {
                $netCall = "$act[netcall], Net #: $act[netid] --> $act[activity] of $act[logdate]";
                echo ("<li role='presentation' data-value=\"$act[netid]\">
                    <a href='#' role='menuitem' onclick = 'showActivities($act[netid])'>
                        $netCall
                    </a></li>
                    <li class=\"divider\"></li>");
            }
        } // end of the query, after the as $act         
    ?>
</ul>
```

Image 1.
[image]

Image 2.
[image]

```
<nav id="admin" class="  navbar navbar-inverse admin flashit roundit" role="navigation">
<!--    <div class=" container-fluid"> -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
          <div class="form-group">

            <input id="cs1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Call Sign"  tabindex=1 onkeyup="showHint(this.value);"  maxlength="16" onmousedown="isKeyPressed(event)" autofocus />

            <input id="Fname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" tabindex=2 onkeyup="nameHint(this.value);" onblur="checkIn();" />

          </div>
        </form>

        <button id="ckin2" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" tabindex=3  >Check In</button>


        <div class="btn-group">
            <span class="dropdown">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Show/Hide
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>  
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="SHOWSTUFF">

                    <li><a href="#">Grid</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">eMail</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lat/Lon</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Last Name</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TOD</a></li>
                </ul>

            </span>
        </div>


        <button id="time" class=" btn btn-info navbar-btn " type="button" onClick="TimeLine();" >Time Line</button>

        <button id="closelog" class=" btn btn-danger navbar-btn closenet "  type="button" value="Close Net" oncontextmenu="rightclickundotimeout();return false;">Close Net</button>    


<!--    </div> --> <!-- end container fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Did I ask the question incorrectly? Someone must have an idea how I can fix this issue. Please!

Comment: Does anyone know of a higher power who might be able to answer or help with my question?